# Add a field to Entity Framework class when selecting with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework 6 database-first, linq and C#.

I have a table `hotel`, and I want to write a linq query to select all columns of `hotel`, plus an additional field that must be selected with a function written in the database. I've added a property to the `hotel` partial class. I don't know how to write linq query, so that I can use the property `hotel.maxHotelPrice` in my code.

My partial class:

```
partial class hotel()
{
    int maxHotelPrice {get; set;}
}
```

My function in edmx:

```
 [EdmFunction("hotelReservation.Core.Data", "getmaxHotelPrice")]
 public static int getmaxHotelPrice(int Hotel_id, DateTime enter_date, DateTime exit_date)
 {
     throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
 }
```